# Full-width thesis header and footer do not extend to right on ipad, but work everywhere else

Tags: wordpress, ipad, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm using the full-width framework for the `wordpress` thesis theme. The site looks fine in all the browsers and on all the computers I could check, but recently saw it on an ipad and the header and footer and navigation do not extend completely to the right side. So confusing and have spent hours trying to solve this. The site is [www.overthinkingmom.com](http://www.overthinkingmom.com). Anyone else with this problem?

Comment: If you visit this site and put in your address does it show the problem? http://ipadpeek.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is getting caused in your CSS with the width:100% style. On iPads in portrait mode, 100% width doesn't fill the whole screen. When we encountered this problem, we added a min-width: value of 1024px; that will fill up the whole screen on an iPad; fixed it for us.